# How to configure WCF timeouts?

Tags: wcf

I have a test WCF application that simply calls a method on the service layer.  I am trying to test WCF timeouts but I can't seem to get the timeout to occur - I've added a thread sleep to simulate a long-running transaction.

I have set the `sendTimeout="00:05:00"` in the client binding configuration but this doesn't seem to have any affect when I add a 15 second thread sleep in the service call.  i.e. the application waits 15 seconds and the result is successfully returned.

**Client Configuration**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <ws2007HttpBinding>
                <binding name="WS2007HttpBinding_IBookService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <security>
                        <transport realm="" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007HttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/bookservice/ws" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WS2007HttpBinding_IBookService" contract="BookServiceReference.IBookService"
                name="WS2007HttpBinding_IBookService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Service Configuration**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetaDataBehaviour" name="Service.BookService">
                <clear />
                <endpoint address="ws" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="Service.IBookService"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                </endpoint>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/bookservice" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MetaDataBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

How do I get the timeout to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 15 seconds is certainly less than 5 minutes (that is the value of `sendTimeout="00:05:00"`).

If you want to simulate a `sendTimeout` violation which would raise a `TimeoutException` then you need to guarantee that the service call will not return until after the `sendTimeout` has been exceeded.

In your particular situation of 5 minutes then this will suffice:

```
public int MyServiceCall()
{
    // Better bring something to read...
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was interpretting 00:05:00 as 5 seconds, not 5 minutes.